# How can transfer get so large when exporting data (15-16MB to over 10GB)

Tags: export, xml

When I try to export a database throught **Wordpresses export-function** (database = about 15-16 MB), I get this in the xml-file created (that is 1kb):

**Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 100663296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45481985 bytes) in row 2935 in functions.php. The limit of transfer is 10GB on the webhotel (space2u). But how could the transfer be so large?

Line 2935 is inside a function that is hooked by:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', array($object, 'callback-function') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing different things. I am not sure what precisely you mean by "transfer" (monthly bandwidth? disk space?), but 10GB figure likely isn't about *memory* (RAM).

Error you are getting *is* about RAM. 100663296 bytes corresponds to just 100MB. That much is *typically* enough for average WP install to function, but might not be enough for some specific functionality or third party code. I think the highest WP tries to request natively is 256 megabytes when manipulating images.

You should inquire with your hosting about RAM available and configuring it to higher value. If that is highest you can get you might not be able to do resource–intensive operations.

Comment: thanks for explanation. Of course I just took for granted that 100663296 was 10GB ;-) I know the hosting have a limit for the database for 100MB. Is that the issue then?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld no, it's not database either. It's RAM (Random Access Memory) as I wrote.

Comment: In case someone else stumbles upon this issue the webhosting company had a memory limit setting of 96MB as default setting for all customers, but increased that to 128MB so I could export my database from WP.